# What toolkits are available to display web pages on an iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app which needs to display in the webbrowser on an iphone. Are there any toolkits out there which can help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use the [WebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html) from the [MapKit framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html)** to embed web content in an iPhone application.

Answer (score 2):

I use jQuery Mobile all the time!

It is great!

http://jquerymobile.com/